# Can't add jQuery handler to HTML site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a single page site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>I'm hosted with GitHub Pages.</p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <FORM>
        <INPUT id="but" Type="BUTTON" Value="About Me" />
    </FORM>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src=script.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And I would like to add some handler to button `#but`, and try to use with script in `script.js`:

```
var mapClicked = function() {
    alert("Map!");
    // create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
    //var map = L.map('map').setView([55.432, 37.654], 13);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#but').click(mapClicked());
});
```

But then I run this html in browser and click to button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding `()` to the function name when referencing the function by it's name. This will call the function directly and the returned value will be assigned as callback of the click event. By removing `()` of the function name(*or rather function call*), the function is referenced correctly and called when the click event occurs on the element.

Change

```
$('#but').click(mapClicked());
```

to

```
$('#but').click(mapClicked); // <----- Removed ()
```

Comment: Also add the libraries which are dependent on jQuery after loading jQuery

Comment: I did it, but also i don't see `alert`(